# Concatenate Using Lambda And Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am trying to using lambda and map to create a new column within my dataframe. Essentially the new column will take column A if a criteria is met and column B is the criteria is not met. Please see my code below.

```
df['LS'] = df.['Long'].map(lambda y:df.Currency if y>0 else df.StartDate)
```

However, when I do this the function returns the entire column to each item in my new column.

In English I am going through each item y in column Long. If the item is > 0 then take the yth value in column "Currency". Otherwise take the yth value in column "Start".

Iteration is extremely slow in running the above. Are there any other options?

Thanks!
James

Comment: `df.[…]` is a syntax error. Are you sure this is exactly the code you are running?

Comment: IIUC you want `df['LS'] = df['Currency'].where(df['Long']>0,df['StartDate'])`

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
df['LS']=np.where(df.Long>0,df.Currency,df.StartDate)
```

which is the good vectored approach.

`df.Long.map` apply to each row, but return actually `df.State` or `df.current`  which are Series.

An other approach is to consider:

```
df.apply(lambda row : row[1] if row[0]>0 else row[2],1)
```

will also work with `df.columns=Index(['Long', 'Currency', 'StartDate', ...])`

but it is not a vectored approach, so it is slow. (200x slower for 1000 rows in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same using [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html#pandas.Series.where):

```
df['LS'] = df['Currency'].where(df['Long']>0,df['StartDate'])
```